# Autolayout in iOS Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I Have a Label, segmented Control, textbox & 2 buttons in a view in iOS.
There are 2 segments. On segment 1 the view should look like image1 , And on selecting segment 2 the view should look like image2.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Each time the respective segments are clicked it should change the layout.

image one is what I get as output initially, but during next selection, it does not change layout. What dio i do to gwt the desired results.

Below is my code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.textview.hidden = true;
    self.btnSMSOut.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.btnCallOut.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
}

- (IBAction)segementA:(id)sender {

    if (self.segmentOutput.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

        [self.btnSMSOut removeConstraints: [self.btnSMSOut constraints]];
        [self.btnCallOut removeConstraints: [self.btnCallOut constraints]];

        self.textview.hidden = true;
        self.btnCallOut.hidden = false;


        [self view1];

    }
    else {

        [self.btnSMSOut removeConstraints: [self.btnSMSOut constraints]];
        [self.btnCallOut removeConstraints: [self.btnCallOut constraints]];

        self.textview.hidden = false;
        self.btnCallOut.hidden = true;
        [self view2];
    }
}

- (void)view2
{
    NSLog(@"function view 1");

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"btnSMS":self.btnSMSOut};

    NSArray *constraint_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[btnSMS(30)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    NSArray *constraint_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[btnSMS(288)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.btnSMSOut addConstraints:constraint_H];
    [self.btnSMSOut addConstraints:constraint_V];





    NSArray *constraint_VPOS = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-343-[btnSMS]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    NSArray *constraint_HPOS = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[btnSMS]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_HPOS];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_VPOS];

}

- (void)view1
{
    NSLog(@"function view 2");

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary2 = @{@"btnCall":self.btnCallOut, @"btnSMS":self.btnSMSOut};

    NSArray *constraint_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[btnCall(30)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary2];

    NSArray *constraint_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[btnCall(115)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary2];

    [self.btnCallOut addConstraints:constraint_H];
    [self.btnCallOut addConstraints:constraint_V];

    NSArray *constraint_VPOS = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-380-[btnSMS]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary2];

    NSArray *constraint_HPOS = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-145-[btnSMS]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary2];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_HPOS];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_VPOS];

    NSArray *constraint_H1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[btnSMS(30)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary2];

    NSArray *constraint_V1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[btnSMS(115)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary2];

    [self.btnSMSOut addConstraints:constraint_H1];
    [self.btnSMSOut addConstraints:constraint_V1];


    NSArray *constraint_VPOSC = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-380-[btnCall]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary2];

    NSArray *constraint_HPOSC = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-145-[btnCall]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary2];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_HPOSC];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_VPOSC];

}
```

Comment: [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; call this in segment action and check

Comment: Its just a suggestion, don't use auto layouts programatically.

Comment: PhaniRaghu What are the alternate solutions, other than using autolayouts programatically

Comment: Create two containerviews with same height and width and add below the `UISegmentedControl`. And place subviews in containerviews. On `UISegmentedControl` action change containerviews height constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the elements in xib and trying to play with constraints that may not work in this case. better try doing the following.

Create all the elements like segment control, buttons, text fields through programming and then add constraints.

When flipping between the segments remove the previous segment and add the new segment content.

Let me know if you have any issues.